# Hyper-V, SMB Shares, Live Migration & Configuration Nightmare with Kerberos?

Tags: server-message-block, hyper-v-server-2012, live-migration

Do I overlook something?

For Live Migration to work in aScenario wher the VM's are stored on a SMB share I have to set up constraint delegation:

http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=13711
http://v-enfra.blogspot.com/2012/04/live-migration-with-smb-shared-storage.html

The problem is: I have to set up every target hyper-v server of my server. THat is a LOT - plus it may be under regular change (i.e. when you add a server to a setup of 20, you ahve to make 20 additional delegations in AD).

Is that not a maintenance nightmare in the making? I mean, my only chance it seems is to make a powershell script that redoes those based on a group membership (of all Hyper-V servers in a "group"), then to manually restart every server to pick up the new delegation configuration.

SERIOUSLY?

Is there no way to say "ok, Server X is allowed to do CIFS and VS MIgration Service deletation to ALL COMPUTERS IN A SPECIFIC GROUP? SOMething that does not require restarts of every machine when one is added or removed and does not make 20 machines a 380 configuration setups nightmare?

Looking for a solution, because this is what we are putting into production now, and I seriously do not like this way to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of using SCVMM 2012 SP1. 
VMM will setup Hyper-V over SMB and there is no requirement to do delegation.

You can also use PowerShell and Remoting.
If you remote into the boxes, you can set everything up without delegation.

Hope this helps,

Jose Barreto

Comment: Thanks. That is on my list anyway (to set up). Funny how one can not set this up out of the box at least with some group membership ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion I have for you is to use SCVMM, which does this for you.